# Async unit testing with NUnit and C#

Tags: c#, asynchronous, nunit

I have the following method I created it's nothing fancy just retrieves data from an HTTP server but it is an async method.

```
public async Task<string> GetStringFromConsul(string key)
    {
        string s = "";

        // attempts to get a string from Consul
        try
        {
            //async method to get the response
            HttpResponseMessage response = await this.http.GetAsync(apiPrefix + key);

            //if it responds successfully
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                //parse out a string and decode said string
                s = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<consulValue>>(s);
                s = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(obj[0].value));
            }
            else
            {
                s = requestErrorCodePrefix + response.StatusCode + ">";
            }
        } 
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            //need to do something with the exception
            s = requestExceptionPrefix + e.ToString() + ">";
        }

        return s;
    }
```

Then in the test I call the code just like I do during normal execution:

```
[Test]
    public async Task GetStringFromConsulTest()
    {
        ConsulConfiguration cc = new ConsulConfiguration();

        string a = cc.GetStringFromConsul("").GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        Assert.AreEqual(a, "");
    }
```

However I get an exception like so instead of any sort of string:

```
Message:   Expected string length 514 but was 0. Strings differ at index 0.
  Expected: "<Request Exception: System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledExcept..."
  But was:  <string.Empty>
```

I've looked around and found a few tutorials on this and tried it but to no avail. If anyone can point me in the right direction I would appreciate it, I'm pretty new to C# unit testing.

Answer (score 2):

In Nunit Framework, Use async/await in unit test as in the following:

```
[Test]
public async Task GetStringFromConsulTest()
{
    ConsulConfiguration cc = new ConsulConfiguration();
    //string a = cc.GetStringFromConsul("").GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    //use await instead

    string a = await cc.GetStringFromConsul("");
    Assert.AreEqual(a, "");
}
```

For more details, read [Async Support in NUnit](http://simoneb.github.io/blog/2013/01/19/async-support-in-nunit/)

It's better to test your method in case of firing exceptions [NUnit expected exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3407765/nunit-expected-exceptions)

**Update:**

The comment:

> I still get the error even when structuring the method like this.

That error  means that the test fail and there is a bug in the source code method `GetStringFromConsul`.

Your test method include the Assert statement:

```
    Assert.AreEqual(a, "");
```

That means that you expect `a` variable which is calculated from `a=cc.GetStringFromConsul("")`  should be "" to pass, 
otherwise the test fail and  NUnit Framework Fire an exception like:

```
    Message:   Expected string length 514 but was 0. Strings differ at index 0.
      Expected: "<Request Exception: System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledExcept..."
      But was:  <string.Empty>
```

To resolve this exception, you should resolve the bug in the method `GetStringFromConsul` to return "" when the input parameter=""

Comment: I still get the error even when structuring the method like this.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a stickler for good error messages so I'd first change the assert to

```
Assert.AreEqual("", a);
```

because the **first** argument is your expected value. Now it will fail with

```
Message:   Expected string length 0 but was 514. Strings differ at index 0.
  Expected:  <string.Empty>
   But was: "<Request Exception: System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledExcept..."
```

...still a failure, but a much more sensible message.

Next, to pass, add an await to your async method call, as suggested by M Hassan.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `this.http.GetAsync(apiPrefix + key);` is timing out.  That would give you a TaskCanceledException.   Not sure what your value of apiPrefix is.