# Net core. Testing timeout dependent method

Tags: c#, unit-testing, .net-core, nunit, moq

I have a method that should make a http call and should wait for response no longer that some timeout. If no response received within timeout time method should return empty string, **BUT** response must be processed later anyway.

```
    async Task<string> GetResponseOrContinue(int timeout, Action<string> responseHandler)
    {
        var task = Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            var response = await _webClient.UploadStringTaskAsync("url", "");
            responseHandler(response);
            return response;
        });

        var emptyTask = Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            await Task.Delay(timeout);
            return string.Empty;
        });

        return await await Task.WhenAny(task, emptyTask);
    }
```

I omitted try/catches and other details for the sake of simplicity...
This code seems to work but I stuck trying to test it.

I wrote test that works correctly almost always, but sometimes something goes wrong with this timeout stuff and test fails.

I mock `UploadStringTaskAsync` call using **Moq framework**:

```
    certWebClient.Setup(x => x.UploadStringTaskAsync(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>()))
        .ReturnsAsync(() =>
        {
            Thread.Sleep(timeout + 10);
            return "this response will be received after timeout";
        });
```

and then pass this **timeout** variable to `GetResponseOrContinue` method. Looks pretty simple but it's not trustworthy...
What can go wrong here and maybe there more appropriate solution for such problem?

Comment: Do no use `Thread.Sleep` in async code, `await Task.Delay(timeout + 10)` is preferred way

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski I tried it with `await Task.Delay(doPaymentTimeout + 1)` too but with no success...

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49338398/async-unit-testing-with-nunit-and-c-sharp help? The idea is to use an `async Task` method in `[Test]` so that you can *await* the call to `GetResponseOrContinue`.

Comment: CancellationToken may be a better pattern to support timeouts of async calls. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/cancel-async-tasks-after-a-period-of-time

Answer (score 1):

One way to unit test this kind of code is to abstract away everything that has to do with threads, tasks, timers, datetimes etc. You could for example inject a special task-factory that returns tasks that may be completed explicitly by your test.

This makes both the code and the tests a bit more complex to write. So I would consider cost/benefit of any particular test.